# What should our documentation contain?

Tags: discussion, 7-essential-questions

Taken from [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), what key things do we want written up, and who wants to write them?

Comment: I've just created the meta-tag [meta-tag:7-essential-questions] - would you like to add it to this question?

Answer (score 4):

It seems to make sense to have a community wiki for this. Anyone with >100 reputation can edit this post and start building up the below.

---

Economics is for academic or professional economists, students of economics,

**Ask about…**

- Specific questions about issues concerning the economy or markets.
- Real problems or questions that you've encountered during research or study of economics.
- Questions about how ideas from economics can be applied more broadly.

**Don’t ask about**

- Stock tips.

**Type of Questions**

- We're very cautious with questions that are politically motivated. Economics is mostly not a normative, but a positive science. Questions that make clear that certain outcomes are *assumed* to be preferred are welcome. Arguing about these positions or taking the as given might lead to lengthy philosophical and political discussions which are off-topic here, and might lead to your question being closed.
- Other stuff that might derail questions

*Good*

- Assume that a policy maker wants to maximize labor-income equality and attaches equal Pareto-weights to the population. How can we implement...

*Not so good*

- We know that it is best for everyone to have the same labor income: How can we effectively implement ....

Comment: I added the point about trying to keep questions neutral. The wording may be off, but I think we should have something of that kind in here. Let me know what you think.